# CSS - styling nth-child selector

Tags: html, css

I have a problem for styling. I want to style a element with different color and the other with nth-child.
Example :

Doesn't work here:

```
<ul class='categories'>
   <li class='skip_class'>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

It work Here:

```
<ul class='categories'>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

```
.categories li.skip_class {
    color: red;
}

.categories li:nth-child(1):not(.skip_class){
    color: green;
}

.categories li:nth-child(2):not(.skip_class){
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?
What are you trying to achieve?

Maybe you are looking for `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove nth child 1 and 2 and do this. it will work:

```
.categories li.skip_class {
    color: red;
}

.categories li:nth-child(2):not(.skip_class){
    color: green;
}

.categories li:nth-child(3):not(.skip_class){
    color: blue;
}
```

for second code:

```
.categories li:nth-child(1){
    color: green;
}

.categories li:nth-child(2){
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work because if apply your code  to the second example, it won't work because skip first child.

Comment: i will edit answer for second code

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
1st child is always the 1st child even if u add skip-class also. 
Must need to add n-child(2) for second child.
```

Comment: i know this, what i want to say please apply your code to both cases

Answer (score -1):

Your nth child numbers are wrong - change the nth child to 2 and 3 respectively then it works:

```
.categories li.skip_class {
    color: red;
}

.categories li:nth-child(2):not(.skip_class){
    color: green;
}

.categories li:nth-child(3):not(.skip_class){
    color: blue;
}
```

And you don’t necessarily need the :not(.skip_class) bit either if you’re just using the nth numbers...

```
.categories li.skip_class {
        color: red;
    }

.categories li:nth-child(2){
        color: green;
    }

.categories li:nth-child(3){
        color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: will that true but your code doesn't work in second case because not every time i add a skip_class element